# how to trim an array format?

Tags: php, arrays

I have to find the difference between two arrays and store in the third one.

this is what I am doing for this

```
$newEmails=array_diff($Emails_1, $Emails_2);
```

Now the problems is `$Emails_1` is in this format ->

```
  array(1) { [0] => string(20) "tester@xyz.com" }
```

and

`$Emails_2` comes in this format ->

```
array(1) { [0] => array(1) { 'email' => string(20) "tester@xyz.com" } }
```

What should I do with `$Emails_2`, so that it come in same format as `$Emails_1`

PS: I can't tamper `$Emails_1`, can only change `$Emails_2`

Comment: so you tagged it as C and php. I don't understand.

Comment: flatten $Emails_2 before doing the diff

Comment: @ Mark Baker - that is my question, how to flatten it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$temp = array();
foreach($Emails_2 as $key => $value){
    $temp[$key] = $value['email'];
}
$Emails_2 = $temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this before comparison

```
$EmailTemp=$Emails_2[0]["email"];
$Emails_2=array();
$Emails_2[0]=$EmailTemp;
```

Comment: its not $email, that was a typo. Use the correct code. its "email"

Answer (score 0):

```
$Emails_1 is in this format -> array(1) { [0] => string(20) "tester@xyz.com" }

$Emails_2 comes in this format -> array(1) { [0] => array(1) { 'email' => string(20) "tester@xyz.com" } }
```

Option 1: Why not just strip the strings from the arrays first,

```
$email1 = $Emails_1[0];

$email2 = $Emails_2[0]['email'];
```

Option 2: Make your array_difference(..) iterative,

```
function array_difference($currentEmails, $comingEmails)
{
    $newEmails = new Array();

    for ($comingEmails as $p)
    {
        if (!in_array($p['email'], $currentEmails))
        {
            $newEmails[]=$p['email'];
        }
    }

    return $newEmails;
}
```